# Scrapy - Create a function pipeline for manual imports pythjon

Tags: python, scrapy, pipeline

In Scrapy, I have a pipeline that does a whole bunch of work for each item it scrapes, I'm looking to create a function that can be used to create an instance of the pipeline manually and pass in the information I need to.

I have 0 experience with OOP and have never used classes before. All of the resources I've looked at include an **init** method that would help me understand, but I'm just lost.

Below is a snippet of what I want to attempt, but I really don't want to break anything.

It would also seem that this is redundant, but again, I don't know what I'm doing. Since I need to be able to run this from a few different places, I think this makes the most sense, but any input would be appreciated.

```
class ItemPipeline:

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        do a bunch of important stuff

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        initialize db

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        close db

def functional_pipeline(argument1 =1, argument2 =False, argument3 ="Manual"):
  ITEM = {argument1: argument1,
          argument2: argument2,
          argument3: argument3}
   pipe = ItemPipeline()
   pipe.item = ITEM
   pipe.open_spider()
   pipe.process_item(item=pipe.item)
   pipe.close_spider()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` method for python classes is a method that runs when you do `pipe = ItemPipeline()`. It isn't mandatory - only really needed when you want to run some code at this step. You don't need one for your current use case of reusing the ItemPipeline.

For the rest of your function - you don't need to make ITEM an attribute of the spider but you need to change the spider arguments to make them optional. So here would be the code you need.

```py
class ItemPipeline:

    def process_item(self, item, spider=None):

        do a bunch of important stuff

    def open_spider(self, spider=None):
        initialize db

    def close_spider(self, spider=None):
        close db

def functional_pipeline(argument1 =1, argument2 =False, argument3 ="Manual"):
  ITEM = {argument1: argument1,
          argument2: argument2,
          argument3: argument3}
   pipe = ItemPipeline()
   pipe.open_spider()
   pipe.process_item(ITEM)
   pipe.close_spider()
```